# How to use jMeter to extract information in a wddx packet?

Tags: xpath, jmeter, wddx

I am a newbie in both using XPath and JMeter.  I have an XML file that contains a wddx packet.  The following is a sample file. The actual data can contain as many as 100 records at a time.

```
<wddxPacket version='1'>
    <header/>
    <data>
        <recordset rowCount='2' fieldNames='FIELD1, FIELD2' type='coldfusion.sql.QueryTable'>
            <field name='FIELD1'>
                <string>MyValue1</string>
                <string>MyValue2</string>
            </field>
            <field name='FIELD2'>
                <string>MyValue3</string>
                <string>MyValue4</string>
            </field>
        </recordset>
    </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

What I need to do is to loop through the XML file based upon the row count specified in the `recordset` tag and then extract the string values in `FIELD1`, `FIELD2`, etc. and use them in some other WebService (SOAP) Sampler. Just to make sure that I can extract the value, I am using the JMeter function, XPath. The XPath call is as follow (I am trying to get `MyValue1`),

```
${__XPath(c:\test.xml, /wddxPacket/data/recordset/field[@name='FIELD1']/string)}
```

Just to make sure that the file reading part is correct, I use the `FileToString()` function and assign the content into a variable. Based upon what I can in the Debug Sampler, the variable does show the correct content. However, using the above function call to XPath and assign the result to a variable, the variable is blank. Here are my questions, as far as extracting the values in an XML file is concerned, am I going about the wrong way? If so, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JMeter, but this XPath

```
/wddxPacket/data/recordset/field[@name='FIELD1']/string
```

does not return a string value, it returns a node set containing the two nodes

```
<string>MyValue1</string> 
<string>MyValue2</string>
```

If you want only the first node you can use this XPath:

```
/wddxPacket/data/recordset/field[@name='FIELD1']/string[1]
```

and if you want just the first string value you could try this XPath:

```
string(/wddxPacket/data/recordset/field[@name='FIELD1']/string)
```

Last but not least: are you sure your XML file does not use any namespace? Because if it does you need to specify them explicitly in your XPaths.

Comment: MiMo, thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, neither of those suggestions work for me.  And yes, I am sure that my XML file does use any namespaces.

Comment: I meant that my XML file does NOT use any namespaces.  Sorry for the typo.